# How to reduce TTFB (Time to first byte) < 30 seconds on single page of website

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I have a WordPress install on an AWS EC2 t2.micro instance running LAMP.

The site is also connected to Cloudfront CDN via W3TC plugin.

The page load time is approx 2-4 seconds on all pages of the website with the exception of the login page which has a TTFB of 31 seconds.

[Login Page](http://wp360.com/my-account)

When I run the page on pingdom it says the server is the only problem and is taking 31 seconds to respond.

I have checked via the command line using curl and get the same response time.

```
$ curl -s -w %{time_total}\\n -o /dev/null http://www.wp360.com/my-account
```

I don't know what to do now to fix the problem now that I have identified it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since the rest of the page seems to work fine, it is probably the code of the login page stalling the server.

Comment: Seems alwas 30 secs + a few more. I'll blindly suggest you to try checking if there's some DNS resolution traking place and failing when you're serving the first page, on your instance as root: `tcdump -nnpi any port 53` then access the homepage with a browser and check tcpdump's output.

Comment: Not quite sure how to do that. Do I run `tcpdump -nnpi anyport 53` from the command line then have a look at the output whilst loading the login page in a browser?

Comment: Yes, it works just like that. Remember to get root privileges before running tcpdump, it doesn't work otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit ironic given the page topic ;) I have some ideas that are too long for a comment, but aren't really an answer, so people please try to resist down-voting. The process of elimination is valuable if it leads to an answer.

I note that according to [WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/161202_8B_00bfc962e5d82de2aa8e2af083f6664d/) even static resources are SUPER slow to download if there's a cache miss - eg 15 seconds to download woocommerce.min.css which is 9kB. That suggest there's something wrong with the server. Check CloudWatch stats, check if you're running out of CPU credits, EBS credits, or if anything else looks odd. Check CPU usage, network, etc. Report back anything odd.

If you can stand a few minutes downtime restart your instance in the AWS EC2 console. This will keep you on the same hardware and just restart the OS, and probably won't help. Next stop and start you instance. This will move you to new hardware and reset your CPU/EBS credits, which might help - again, probably not, but it's worth trying the easy things first.

I assume you can't mess with your production server, but you're in AWS so test servers are cheap. Clone your instance via a snapshot, and clone the database if it's in RDS - either another DB on the same server or a new server, whatever you like. If the DB is on the server that's fine. Ensure that reproduces the problem. If not... well that's interesting information.

Next disable ALL plugins. If this fixes the problem enable them until you get the problem again. If it doesn't fix the problem try the stock 2016 theme. If that doesn't fix the problem try a fresh Wordpress install. If that doesn't fix the problem report back anything interesting you find, as you'll have a lot more information to share. Edit your question with new information, and if you want to get my attention tag my name in a comment on this answer.